# Sharepoint 2007 B2C 

Tags: 2007

Can you do a write to database using BDC in Sharepoint 2007 ?

Answer (score 1):

BDC out of the box its Read only in 2007 this is one of the new features of 2010

Comment: can you customise and make it write in sp2007

Comment: You will need to do custom code to write to the db but not using bdc probably, all depends on you requirements